# How to fetch just the "_id" field from MongoDB find()

Tags: mongodb

I wish to return just the document id's from mongo that match a `find()` query.

I know I can pass an object to exclude or include in the result set, however I cannot find a way to just return the `_id` field.

My thought process is returning just this bit of information is going to be way more efficient (my use case requires no other document data just the `ObjectId`).

An example query that I expected to work was:

```
collection.find({}, { _id: 1 }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    ...
}
```

However this returns the entire document and not just the `_id` field.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a projection to find what ya want.

```
collection.find({filter criteria here}, {foo: 0, bar: 0, _id: 1});
```

Since I don't know what your document collection looks like this is all I can do for you. `foo: 0` for example is exclude this property.

Comment: This is what I thought, I need to know all the document properties upfront. This is fine, I just thought there would be a nicer way to write it. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't actually work. The `toArray()` on the find produces a cursor and the documents it returns (regardless of the projection) include all fields. I have just executed this:

`collection.find({}, { field1: 0, field2: 0 }).toArray(function(err, docs) { console.dir(docs[0]); }`

And both field 1 & 2 are printed.

Comment: can you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question more so I can help?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the cursor object directly I can specify the required projection. The `mongodb` package on npm when calling `toArray()` is returning the entire document regardless of the projection specified in the initial `find()`. Fixed working example below that satisfies my requirements of just getting the `_id` field.

Example document:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(...),
  test1: "hello",
  test2: "world!"
}
```

---

Working Projection

```
var cursor = collection.find({});
cursor.project({
    test1: 0,
    test2: 0
});

cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
    // Importantly the docs objects here only
    // have the field _id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `_id` is by definition unique, you can use [`distinct`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#distinct) to get an array of the `_id` values of all documents as:

```
collection.distinct('_id', function(err, ids) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I reached the 16mb document limit

Comment: Ah, yep, there are limits. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
collection.find({},'_id').toArray(function(err, docs) {
    ...
}
```